# *.herokuapp.com SSL warning still appearing on domain

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

Recently, I've begun trying to deploy my Heroku app to my domain name. I've added SSL Endpoint, bought a cert, configure the cert, and changed the DNS. Yet I still get the warning `You attempted to reach www.foo.com but instead reaching a server identified as *.herokuapp.com`

I've read the [SSL Endpoint documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint), [DNSimple's documentation](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/ssl-certificate-with-heroku), but nothing seems to fix this.

Here's what is returned from the usual perpetrators:

```
$ heroku certs
Endpoint                  Common Name(s)           Expires            Trusted
----------------------  ----------------------  --------------------  -------
SSL_NAME.herokussl.com   www.foo.com, foo.com    2014-09-17 04:29 UTC  True

$ heroku domains
=== foo Domain Names
www.foo.com
foo.com
foo.herokuapp.com
```

And the DNS records (via DNSimple):

```
CNAME   www.foo.com SSL_NAME.herokussl.com
ALIAS   foo.com     SSL_NAME.herokussl.com
TXT     foo.com     ALIAS for SSL_NAME.herokussl.com
```

I've also tried just simply:

```
CNAME   www.foo.com     SSL_NAME.herokussl.com
URL     foo.com         https://www.foo.com
```

Am I missing something here? I have waited multiple days for the DNS changes to go into effect, yet this is still occurring. If any other information would help, just let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I forgot that I had the Zerigo DNS add-on installed which had a CNAME record pointed to proxy.herokuapp.com. I removed the add-on (since my DNS was configured elsewhere) and it works as it should!